# Issue connecting to git repository : SSL Certificate error

Tags: git, ssl

This issue is a variant on the `the SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` issue.

I am trying to connect to a git repository only given the url which is: `git.repoName.net.au`. However, when I try to pull from origin I get the SSL certificate problem message.

I used this code to solve it:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

This partially works as I then get a message as:

```
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
asked for: http://git.repoName.net.au/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: https://git.repoName.net.au/user/login
```

I have tried updating my login credentials as given (username, email and password) using the following commands

```
git config user.name "Username"  
git config user.email "Email@Domain.ru"  
git config user.password "password"
```

But this also doesn't work. I was mentioned that they use a ssh connection. However, as far as my understanding works I had to be given a public key to connect to - or setup one on the server.

Any advice on how to connect to this repo will be appreciated.

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with authentication. They're used for authoring commits. `user.password` means nothing to Git, but you probably shouldn't set it anyway.

Comment: "I was mentioned that they use a ssh connection"—if this is true you need to use an SSH URL, and SSL is irrelevant.

Comment: Try changing your remote from `http://...` to `https://...` and see if that prompts you for your username and password.